# global variable 'map' is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a global variable, map, declared after the opening script tag - I also have a global variable, test_var, declared right underneath. In the initialize function, I use the google maps api to create a new google map and assign it to the global variable map. Outside of the function, I initialize the map and attempt to console.log(map) and console.log(test_var). The former returns undefined and the latter returns 42, but they are both global variables, so I don't understand why the map, after assigning it a value in the initialize function, then calling that initialize function now has an undefined value.

One more thing: in the console if I try to access map, or a map method like map.getBounds(), it works fine. The question is, why cant I do this programmatically and not just in the console window. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Heatmaps</title>
    <style>
    //.......some styling.....//
    </style>
    <body>
       /....some html..../
    </body>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=visualization"></script>
<script>
var map;
test_var = 42; 

var home = new google.maps.LatLng(50, -15) //map is centered somewhere in the atlantic ocean, change later

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: home,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      panControl: false,
      zoomControl: true,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      scaleControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      overviewMapControl: false
  };

  var styles = [
  {
    stylers: [
      { "gamma": 0.83 },
      { hue: "#00ffe6" },
      { saturation: -20 }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "road",
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [
      { lightness: 100 },
      { visibility: "simplified" }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "road",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
];

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
console.log(test_var); //this works!
console.log(map); //get undefined error, why?????

 </script>
  </head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your event handler (function `initialize`) is not yet called when you call `console.log(map)`. Try adding `console.log(map)` to a button

```
<input type=button onclick="console.log(map)" value="Test map" />
```

Comment: But how it is not called I thought  `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize)` called it. Also, I know the button method will work, but actually I want to access map methods (like map.getBounds()) in javascript and not in the console or html

Comment: `addDomListener` does not call the method. It attaches an event handler to the event you specify (`window.onload`) and only in that event will your method be called. Try adding `console.log` inside of your method and you will see it executes after your current `console.log` calls.