# how to define map as global variable to call in another javascript function

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I am stuck for searching this solution for hours please help, this is my code,

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Simple markers</title>
        <style>
          html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px
          }
        </style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var map;
            var marker;

            function initialize() {
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);

                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 10,
                    disableDefaultUI: true,
                    center: myLatlng
                }

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: myLatlng,
                  map: map,
                  title: 'Hello World!'
                });
            }
            function see(){
                alert(map);
                var newLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,133.044922);
                map.setCenter(newLatlng);
            }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
see();
      </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

the variable `map` is called undefined. After searching they said map is called before map is assigned ([global variable 'map' is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114242/global-variable-map-is-undefined)). How to fix this known isue? please help

My goal is to update marker position by using javascript function. Any help would be great, Thank you (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the other post says, maps has not been assigned yet when it is referenced. This is because your initialize function is only going to get called when the page is done loading. In that function the following happens.

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
```

Until then, map is undefined even though you var'ed it. Therefore, you can either call your function when you hit a button as the other post recommended, or you can call see() at the end of the initialize function. Either will work. Here I put see() at the end of your initialize function.

```
<html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Simple markers</title>
        <style>
          html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px
          }
        </style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var map;
            var marker;

            function initialize() {
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);

                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 10,
                    disableDefaultUI: true,
                    center: myLatlng
                }

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: myLatlng,
                  map: map,
                  title: 'Hello World!'
                });
                see();
            }
            function see(){
                alert(map);
                var newLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,133.044922);
                map.setCenter(newLatlng);
            }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
      </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: it is weird that I try it last time (calling see from button onclick) its give me an error, but now it isn't ._.
I am sorry for my impatience asking question ._.